# how to handle absolute position inside div container css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I would like to achieve this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLVIL.jpg

My Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/49MIr.jpg

My Code:

```
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        padding: '25px',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '350px',
        margin: '45px',
        borderRadius: '25px',
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '10%',
          height: '50%',
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          borderRadius: '10px',
          top: '240px',
          left: '550px',
          transform: 'rotate(-40deg)',
        }}
      />
      <div style={{ width: '70%', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>blue</div>
      <div style={{ width: '30%', backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>
        <div>orange</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want the gray div to not be positioned above the yellow container, how can I achieve that, thank you very much :))))

Comment: You could add this to the yellow container: `overflow: 'hidden', position:'relative'`. But note that now, the gray div's position & dimensions will be relative to that yellow div, and may need to be ajusted as well

Comment: thanks blex, it worked :)